# Mudar cor do item da List View se ele estiver desativado - Android

Tags: java, android, listview

Tenho uma listview normal que lista os nomes dos meus usuários.

E gostaria que os usuários desativados, ficassem com o fundo cinza do list item.  Como fazer isso?

```
public class Usuario {

private String nome;
private String endereco;
private Boolean ativo;


//construtor
// getters e setters

}
```

Ou seja, se ativo for true, deixar normal. Se for false, deixar de cor cinza.

Como faço pra mudar cor do item da List View se ele estiver desativado?

Comment: Está usando `Adapter` no preenchimento da ListView?

Comment: O próprio ArrayAdpater. não perosnalizei o meu.

Comment: Então, pelo que andei lendo, dá pra dar um `override` na função "isEnabled" do `BaseAdapter`, eu nunca tentei!

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso de maneira adequada, você precisa criar um `Adapter` que receberá seu usuário, fará a verificação de ativo e inativo e criará um item da `ListView` para ele.

Você vai precisar de:

1. Uma classe ( *e.g.* `UsuarioListAdapter`) que extende `BaseAdapter`;
2. Um layout ( *e.g.* `adapter_item_usuario`),que o `UsuarioListAdapter` usará para colocar os dados da sua classe `Usuario`.

Mãos à obra!

- Crie o layout para os itens da lista:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <TextView android:id="@+id/textview_nome"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/textview_endereco"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
  ```
- Agora crie a classe que extendera o `BaseAdapter`:

  ```
  public class UsuarioListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

      Context mContext;
      List<Usuario> mUsuarios = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

      public UsuarioListAdapter(Context context, List<Usuario> usuarios){

          mContext = context;
          mUsuarios = usuarios;
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return mUsuarios.size();
      }

      @Override
      public Object getItem(int position) {
          return mUsuarios.get(position);
      }

      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
          return position;
      }

      // Neste método que é feita a verificação e a mudança de cor do item
      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){

      LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_item_usuario,null);

      // Verificação e mudança de cor
      if(mUsuario.get(position).estaAtivo == false){

          view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Grey);

      }

      TextView mTextviewNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_noticia);
      TextView mTextViewEnderco = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_noticia_data);

      mTextviewNome.setText(mUsuarios.get(position).getNome());
      mTextViewEnderco.setText(mUsuarios.get(position).getEndereco());

      return view;
  }
  ```

Agora, ao invés de você criar um `SimpleArrayAdapter`, crie um `UsuarioListAdapter` passando os parâmetros corretos e setando ele como adapter da sua `ListView`.